# How to receive Snmp V3 traps in Camel SNMP?

Tags: apache-camel, snmp, snmp4j

I was trying to get Snmp v3 traps using Apache Camel SNMP component. I got both v1 and v2 traps but I am not able to get the v3.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport;
import org.apache.camel.main.MainListenerSupport;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.camel.component.snmp.*;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.StartupListener;
import org.snmp4j.security.*;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import java.util.*;
import org.snmp4j.smi.*;
import org.snmp4j.mp.*;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.*; 

public final class Snmp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // CamelContext contains methods to add routes, components etc
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        // work with Snmp component
        context.addComponent("snmp", new SnmpComponent());

        // Add the route
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {

                // When a SNMP TRAP is received on port 162 from any source..
                System.out.println(new OctetString("MD5DES"));
                System.out.println(SnmpConstants.version3);
                System.out.println(AuthMD5.ID);
//              from("snmp:0.0.0.0:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP&securityName="+new OctetString("MD5DES")+"&snmpVersion="+SnmpConstants.version3+"&securityLevel="+SecurityLevel.NOAUTH_NOPRIV).process(myProcessor);
                from("snmp:0.0.0.0:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP&securityName="+new OctetString("MD5DES")+"&snmpVersion="+SnmpConstants.version3+"&securityLevel="+SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV+"&authenticationPassphrase=UserName&privacyPassphrase=PasswordUser&authenticationProtocol=MD5&privacyProtocol=DES").process(myProcessor).to("file://D:/traps.log");
                }
            });

        // Get notification when the context is started..
        context.addStartupListener(new StartupListener(){
            public void onCamelContextStarted(CamelContext context, boolean alreadyStarted)
            {
                System.out.println("Camel context is started");
            }
        });

            // Start the context
            context.start();

            // Sleep for sometime, so that the context can keep running
            // otherwise the program exits
            Thread.sleep(1000000);

            context.stop();
    }

    public static Processor myProcessor = new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange trap) throws Exception {

            System.out.println(trap.getIn().getHeaders());

            // getIn() means get the inbound message
            // Since we are using Snmp, we get SnmpMessage object, we need to typecast from Message
            SnmpMessage msg=(SnmpMessage)trap.getIn();

            // PDU refers to SNMP4J PDU class, the camel SNMP component internally uses it
            PDU pdu=msg.getSnmpMessage();



            // Get the VariableBindings (i.e.) the list of OID and value pairs
            // print them each
            pdu.getVariableBindings().forEach(System.out::println);
            /*
            Vector<? extends VariableBinding> v=pdu.getVariableBindings();

                for(VariableBinding b:v)
                {
                    System.out.println(b.getSyntax());
                }
            */
        }
    };

    public static class PrintBean {


        // This also does the same thing
        public void print(String msg)
        {
                System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

While I am sending the trap, the trap is being sent successfully. But I am not able to get into the `myProcessor`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able"? What happened when you tried?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not getting any error on the sender side which I would get if the security mechanism doesn't par with whats on the receiver side

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Though IIRC the spec requires a "not authorised" response, it's not an unusual real-world practice to just stay silent if receiving an unauthorised request. That way you don't advertise the existence of a service to would-be attackers, prompting them to keep trying.

Comment: We still don't have even close to enough information to diagnose this for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How do I enable the debug log for camel?

Comment: First Google result for `apache camel debug log` tells you

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have tried it previously, but with no success

Comment: Well then that is a different question from "how do I enable the debug log". Please get into the habit of thoroughly explaining your problems.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is there any problem with the part of the code that is written in the question? Are the parameters and their values ok?

Comment: I cannot make any comment about one line of code taken out of context. Present a MCVE.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Updated the post